# How to bind Toolbar MenuItem.IsEnabled with MvvmCross and Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Using MvvmCross and Xamarin.Android is it possible to bind the IsEnabled property of a Toolbar MenuItem to a boolean value in a viewmodel?  If so, how is it done?

Comment: It's possible to bind any public member of Android control to a property in your ViewModel. It may help you to read the relevant section of the wiki if you're struggling to achieve that: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/databinding

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's impossible at this time to bind Android IMenuItem.IsEnabled to a boolean value on a viewmodel due to the fact that IsEnabled is readonly and changed the enabled state of a menu item requires a call to `SetIsEnabled(bool)`.

I worked around this limitation by adding an event handler for `MvxViewModel.PropertyChanged` in the Activity/Fragment.  All my viewmodels inherit from `MvxViewModel` so I'll share *a* way this can be accomplished.  Most of my app is implemented with Fragments, so my example reflects that, (in my actual code I've put most of this in a base Fragment class, but I wanted to keep it simple):

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
   public bool MenuItemIsEnabled {
       get{return _menuItemIsEnabled;}
       set{SetProperty(ref _menuItemIsEnabled, value);
   }
}

[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register(nameof(MyFragment))]
public class MyFragment : MvxFragment
{
   private Toolbar Toolbar;

   //menuitem whose enabled state should change with viewmodel property
   private IMenuItem MyMenuItem;       

   public new MyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (MyViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

   public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        //we'll need the Toolbar later when we set up the IsEnabled "binding"
        Toolbar = view.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        return view;
    }

    public override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();

        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        //create the menu based on a menu resource
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.my_menu, menu);

        //save a reference to the menu item so we can update it when the viewmodel changes
        MyMenuItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.my_menu_item);

        //set the initial enabled state based on the viewmodel
        MyMenuItem.SetEnabled(ViewModel.MenuItemIsEnabled);
    }

    private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //when ViewModel.MenuItemIsEnabled is updated, update the menuitem enabled state as well
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.MenuItemIsEnabled ))
           BinContentsMenuItem?.SetEnabled(ViewModel.MenuItemIsEnabled);
    }
}
```

This should be considered pseudocode, since it's trying to demonstrate the general concepts I used to work around my original problem.

Comment: You could also use WeakSubscribe on your ViewModel to only get changes for that specific Property. Then you also don't have to unsubscribe any events to not leak memory.

Comment: Ok, that actually worked great and makes it so much easier, thanks :)